# Allow user to select field widget at node form

Tags: 7, entities

How can I allow user to select field widget type directly at node's form page?

I have [entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) field, and editor wants in some cases input values as multiple autocomplete fields, and another time as autocomplete tagging style. Is there any module for this?